# In the google API console what application do I register for, when my application will be on a internal server

Tags: php, google-analytics

My application is on a internal server, and because Google is migrating their API from 2.3 to 2.4 I am following the migration guide which tells me to register my application, the problem is my application is based on a internal server so I am not sure which type to register for. Web application seems the plausible one but they seem to only allow localhost or a external domain. But how can this be possible when localhost is a internal domain?